# How to know if a woman has a wet dream and is Ghusl required?

Tags: women, ghusl, nocturnal-emission

If you do **not** remember having a wet dream, but you see some discharge, then should you do ghusl?

It is confusing because as a woman I have discharge anyway, so I do not know if it is a sign of a wet dream or not.

Comment: I think my answer on [I am having orgasms while sleeping specifically when i don't recite duas ...](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/57055/i-am-having-orgasms-while-sleeping-specifically-when-i-dont-recite-duas-before) addresses your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you found the same discharge that comes after sexual intercross so you must do ghusl even if you dreamed or not.

The point is the coming of the sexual discharge out. Once you saw it -even without dream-so you must do ghusl

Note that:

The liquid which comes from the woman after sexual intercross can be noticed by two main things:

1- it is a light yellow liquid.

2- its smell is like the smell of the dough or the smell of the pollen of palm trees.

References: [Fiqh-us-Sunnah](http://www.islamawareness.net/Ghusl/fiqh_us_sunnah.html) and Female Wet Dreams on [muslimmatters](http://muslimmatters.org/2010/03/08/female-wet-dreams/)