# Does tiny amount of discharge from arousal affect wudu?

Tags: salat, wudu

Salam,

I am a woman and I have this very embarrassing issue. Sometimes (particularly the week following my period and the week before it) I cannot help but get this type of discharge while doing wudu. Even if I think something arousing for a mili-second I can feel something and I get this cloudy discharge.

I am honestly trying my best, but it is becoming physically exhausting to do wudu in a way where I will not get discharge from arousal, and I have to re-do my wudu which makes me miss my prayer. I am very stressed about this. Please let me know what I should do.

Comment: See also: "[how to know if a woman has a wet dream and is Ghusl required?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28895/9123)" and "[Does dripping break Wudu?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2955/9123)"

Answer (score -2):

From [Does discharge required wudu?](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/fatwaa-dot-com/79965):

> Q. Many women experience a clear or white discharge during their normal pure period. Is this discharge impure and does it invalidate wudhu?
>
> A. Vaginal discharge can be categorized into three types:
>
> 1. Discharge from the outer private part. This discharge is pure and can be likened to perspiration.
> 2. Discharge from the inner private part. This is normally experienced during a woman’s pure period. This is also pure and does NOT invalidate wudhu.
> 3. Discharge from the womb. This is normally experienced during menses. This is impure and invalidates wudhu.
>
> From the above we can conclude that the clear or white discharge experienced during a pure period is pure and does not invalidate wudhu.
>
> NOTE: This ruling is applicable as long as the discharge is clear or white. If it is mixed with blood or discharge due to arousal (mazi), the wudhu will be invalidated.