# I am having orgasms while sleeping, specifically when i don't recite duas before sleeping

Tags: women, dua, jinn, dream, nocturnal-emission

I remember when my Arabic tutor told me girls who do not recite duas before sleeping are visited by jinns and they can cause physical harm if they have intercourse with them. For the past few days, due to some school related stress i couldn't recite duas and i started to have orgasms frequently in my dreams, now i am fearing something bad has been happening to me all those nights, i just want to know if this is actually true, that jinns can have intercourse with the women who do not recite Allah's verses before sleeping. And this specifically happens when i don't recite duas, as told before, and i noticed one night when i recited them and i had no trouble sleeping. Plus i am a teenager so is there any chance that puberty and hormones are causing all of this? I'd really appreciate if someone answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

We may read in the sunnah:

> Anas b. Malik reported:
>   Umm Sulaim who was the grandmother of Ishaq came to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) in the presence of 'A'isha and said to him: Messenger of Allah, in case or woman sees what a man sees in dream and she experiences in dream what a man experiences (i. e. experiences orgasm)? Upon this 'A'isha remarked: O Umm Sulaim, you brought humiliation to women;may your right hand be covered with dust. He (the Holy Prophet) said to 'A'isha: Let your hand be covered with dust, and (addressing Umm Sulaim) said: Well, O Umm Sulaim, she should take a bath if she sees that (i. e. she experiences orgasm in dream).
>   (Source [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/3/31), see also these versions in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/3/72), [al-Muwatta'](https://sunnah.com/urn/501170), [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/122) and in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/237) etc.)

---

A bit off-topic:

Umm Sulaim is also the mother of the sahabi Anas ibn Malik.

This hadith in first place explains why the 'Aishah () uttered the statement:

> 'A'isha said: How good are the women of Ansar (helpers) that their shyness does not prevent them from learning religion.

Which one may find in another version of the hadith in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/3/72), [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/316) and [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1306840).

Therefore it is a bad habit in Islam to remain silent and not ask if one has doubt or don't know about a manner it is even sinful and it is also a bad manner in Islam to accuse or denounce somebody who asks something that might be regarded as shameful in order to get knowledge. 
We must all be aware that:

> “All the sons of Adam are sinners, but the best of sinners are those who repent often.”  (See for example in [Bulugh al-Maram](https://sunnah.com/urn/2117860))

so accusing or hating somebody because of his sins is wrong.

---

The hadith shows that:

- this is a natural thing and that women may also have nocturnal emissions.
- anybody who has nocturnal emissions must perform ghusl in order to be able to pray and worship Allah.
- Having these emissions is not sinful nor has any relation to jinn,

  > The Pen is lifted from the minor, the insane person and the sleeper."
  >   (See for example in [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1263610))

  but ghusl is required to reach the state of *taharah* (ritual purity) again.

Nevertheless as this happens while sleeping and is caused  by dreams we know also from the sunnah that:

> "A good dream is from Allah, and a bad dream is from Satan; so, if anyone of you had a bad dream which he disliked, then he should spit on his left and seek refuge with Allah from it, for it will not harm him."
>   (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/91/23) and [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/42/1))

Therefore it is recommended to seek refuge from satan and perform the recommended du'a's before sleeping etc. further it is recommended to avoid watching at anything that may cause sexual arousal.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing out my confusions, may Allah shower us all with His blessings.